# Flask image upload in HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, terminal, image-uploading

So, I wanted to upload an image in my website(HTML). The box does show up when I run the code but it does not show the image, instead it shows the image name. This is the code I used:
    app = Flask(**name**)

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image.jpg') }}" alt="image.jpg" width=208 length=284>
```

I did try putting my image and code in the directory : `/html/static`

I even tried a code as simple as this but it didn't work:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/new')
def new_file():
    return """

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
This is an image.
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image.jpg') }}" alt="image.jpg"     width=208 length=284>
</p>
</body>
</html>"""

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you load the  `/static/image.jpg` URL directly in your browser, or does that give a 404 error?

Comment: Unless you have a `static` directory in the same location as your main flask code, the link will not work.

Comment: Note that Flask has its own `static` *directory* as part of the project. Is `/htm/static` a different location on your hard disk? If so that won't work without additional configuration.

Comment: The 404 didn't appear in the page however it was in terminal. (where I had run the code)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the img tag is properly in a template and that the `app = Flask(__name__)` is NOT in a template, you just copied them both into the example?

It looks like you have a problem with quotation marks. Essentially, you shouldn't use double-quotes "inside" a double-quote string. Here's an example with the mistake: `"This is "the" wrong method".`
Here's an example without the mistake: `"This is 'the' correct method."` Notice I've replaced the double-quotes inside the string with single-quotes.

Here's how you would apply it to your code:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image.jpg') }}" alt="image.jpg" width=208 length=284>
```

I've replaced the double quotation marks around the filename with single quotation marks.
Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Can you show your full python code and the full template code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the **static** folder which you are using in **url_for** should be there within your application folder and not some separate folder in something like **/html/static**

I have been following the application structure from Miguel Grinberg Flask Blog:

```
Your Application\
  app\
    static\
    templates\
    __init__.py
    views.py
    routes.py
  manage.py
```

Your image should be inside the **app/static** folder so that its url can be automatically generated by using **url_for**.

Also, make sure to use single quotes around the image name, if double quotes have been used outside. You can refer to:

[Having both single and double quotation in a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487145/having-both-single-and-double-quotation-in-a-python-string)