# InfluxDB - query working on Grafana but not in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, influxdb, influxdb-python

I'm trying this query from Grafana and it works perfectly:
SELECT * FROM "x" WHERE time > '2020-03-31' AND time < '2020-04-02'

The problem is, in python I have to format the query as a string, and I run into the following problems:

1) if I use double quotes around the whole line, I get invalid syntax because the FROM field requires double quotes already (and I get influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400 if I try to use single quotes around the FROM field)

2) if I use single quotes around the whole line, it sees the dates as int and returns invalid syntax

3) if I don't use quotes at all around the whole line, I get invalid syntax

4) if I use single double quotes around the dates it returns 0 elements

5) if I use single quotes and wrap dates with str() I get either 0 elements or syntax error depending if still use quotes inside the str() or not

6) if I try to wrap the whole line in str() I get syntax error

I tried all of those with both:
result = client.query(q, chunked=True).get_points()
result = list(client.query(q, chunked=True).get_points())

I'd prefer to use the list if possible.
InfluxDB 1.7.9, Influx Python Client 5.2.3, Python 3.7, MacOs 10.12.6

Comment: Fixed using: "SELECT * FROM \"x\" WHERE time > '2020-03-31' AND time < '2020-04-02'"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it can work but you could try to use **triple quotes**. The questions of mixing single and double quotes was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487171/13187605).

Example:

```
print(""" I'm "Bob" """)
```

Use spaces around the triple space otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Already fixed using \"x\" and double quotes around the whole thing, see comments above. Thank you anyway!