# What is the function of the second slash in a python print function. I know the first is an escape sequence but i dont understand why they have 2

Tags: python

here is the code:

```py
print('Hello World\nIt\'s hot today')
```

okay I get the first slash is an escape sequence but whats  the second slash for ?

Comment: That's to escape `'`. Try removing ```\``` there and re-running the code.

Comment: first `\n` is for new line. second `\`is for escaping apostrophe.

Comment: Here is a list of all of the escape sequences in python: https://www.python-ds.com/python-3-escape-sequences

Comment: `\n` is a new line, `\'` is an escaped quote (which would not be necessary if the string itself used double quotes... `print("Hello World\nIt's hot today")` does the same)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having both single and double quotation in a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487145/having-both-single-and-double-quotation-in-a-python-string)

Comment: The second slash is used to escape the single quote ('). Without the slash, the string would have ended at 'Hello World\nIt' because python interpreter will think the single quote signifies end of your string.

Answer (score 2):

`print('Hello World\nIt\'s hot today')`

The 2nd slash here, which appears before a `'` character, allows you to use this character in a string which is scoped with it (otherwise, the Python interpreter has to conclude that this character is where the string ends).

Alternatively, you could scope this string with `"` instead of `'`, which would make that 2nd slash redundant:

```
print("Hello World\nIt's hot today")
```

Answer (score 2):

The second `\` is to escape `'`. Without this, python would see

```
'Hello World\nIt's hot today'
```

Now, it would interpret `'Hello world\nIt'` as a string, because you ended it with `'`!  Then it does not know what to do with the rest of your code `s hot today'`, resulting in an syntax error.

To avoid escaping `'`, you could instead use `"`:

```
print("Hello World\nIt's hot today")
```

---

The same goes for escaping `"`. If you want to print a string `He said "Hello, world!"`, then you would want either one of the following:

```py
print("He said \"Hello, world!\"")
print('He said "Hello, world!"')
```